# Under what conditions does the "large list" moniker appear in RStudio?

Tags: r, list, rstudio

While working with lists, I realized that a list I was working with has a description of `Large list (113 elements, 4.8 MB)`.

Weirdly, after adding a column to each of the dataframes in the first list, the resulting list is simply described as `List of 113` even though the memory size should be larger.

Here is a screen capture of the two lists' description in the environment.

[image]

`list2` has one more column in each of the 113 dataframes than `list1`.

The fact that the size of `list2` being larger than `list1` is also confirmed.

```
> object.size(list1)
4760400 bytes
> object.size(list2)
5023240 bytes
```

What are the conditions for R Studio to describe a list as a "[large] list"? My guess was a list over a certain size, but the example above disproves that.

Comment: RStudio Community Forums might be a better place to ask this question as it's more about the RStudio user experience than it is about programming

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string that describes the object in the environment pane is obtained internally by the function `.rs.describeObject`

If I create a list of data frames which is 5.8MB in size, we can see that this matches the output in the environment panel:

```r
set.seed(1)

list1 <- lapply(1:113, function(x) as.data.frame(replicate(20, rnorm(300))))
```

[image]

We can get the same description string by running the code:

```r
.rs.describeObject(.GlobalEnv, "list1")$value
#> [1] "Large list (113 elements,  5.8 MB)"
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "rs.scalar"
```

Looking at the code of the function, the size above which an object is labelled as "Large" is 524288, i.e. half a megabyte, determined by this line of code:

```r
    if (size > 524288) {
```

However, this does not explain why your second list does not have the "Large" adjective applied to it. As it happens, I cannot replicate your findings, since if I do:

```r
list2 <- lapply(list1, function(x) {x$a <- rnorm(300); x})
```

I now have

[image]

It seems there are some contexts in which the third argument to `.rs.describeObject`, which is `computeSize` may be set to `FALSE` and cause the object size not to be calculated in the environment pane. Without knowing the code you used to create the "silently large" `list2`, it's not possible to trace this through.

**TL;DR**

The bottom line is that most of the time, an object is "Large" if it is greater than half a megabyte, but depending on how the object was created, its size may not be calculated in the environment pane.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Allan! That satisfies my curiosity.